# Allow only comma separated numbers in input field using angular js

Tags: javascript, angularjs, regex

I am using angular js and below is my code which allows only numbers separated by comma.But regex which I used allows user to enter 1,,,2.

Is there any way so that I can restrict user to enter only one comma after each number?

Plunker - http://plnkr.co/edit/g1X9ldVuH4ZewAlumM1P?p=preview

```
  function NumberValidator() {
    return {
        require: '?ngModel',
        link: function(scope, element, attrs, ngModelCtrl) {
            if (!ngModelCtrl) {
                return;
            }

            ngModelCtrl.$parsers.push(function(val) {
                var clean = val.replace(/[^\d+(,\d+)*$]/g, '');
                if (val !== clean) {
                    ngModelCtrl.$setViewValue(clean);
                    ngModelCtrl.$render();
                }
                return clean;
            });

            element.bind('keypress', function(event) {
                if (event.keyCode === 32) {
                    event.preventDefault();
                }
            });
        }
    };
```

Answer (score 2):

Remove the `clean` part and replace the if condition with,

```
if (!/^\d+(?:,\d+)*$/.test(val)) {
```

This code would test whether the given value is in `1,2,3` or `1` or `3,4` formats or not.

*Example:*

```js
console.log(!/^f+$/.test('ff'))

console.log(!/^f+$/.test('df'))
```

Think you want something like this,

```
str.replace(/[^\d,]|^,+|,+$|,+(?=,)/gm, '')
```

[PLNKR](http://plnkr.co/edit/C5Mu4vMRMMo7oPSmaJTr?p=preview)

Comment: How this would work, as I want to restrict the users to enter numbers followed by a comma in a text box, So I am using replace function

Comment: no need for replace func.. Just check each letter (on key press) with this `^\d+(?:,\d+)*$` regex. If it's not true then show the box in red color. If it's true then show it in green color.

Comment: I don't want to change text box color. Even if user press other characters it should not be shown in text box hence i am using replace

Comment: then use a replace like `str.replace(/[^\d,]/g, '')` . This would replace any char but not of comma or digit with an empty string

Comment: This allows users to enter string like ,,,21312321,,,, or 2232,,,, which is invalid. It should always allow digit followed by only one comma like 1,3,4

Comment: ok, then do a replace `str.replace(/[^\d,]/g, '')` then check the resultatnt string with this `^\d+(?:,\d+)*$` regex.

Comment: Thanks Avinash. I tested with my code, but still no success. Comma is getting replaced :-(. In the demo link it is working fine

Comment: pls make a fiddle demo.

Comment: try http://plnkr.co/edit/C5Mu4vMRMMo7oPSmaJTr?p=preview . It should show last comma since it won't know whether there is any continuation or line end

Comment: Thanks Avinash. Working fine